# How to use a for loop in R to create multiple plots

Tags: r, for-loop, ggpubr

I have the following code, which works fine, but I am wondering if the last 4 lines could be run using a for loop? I was not sure how to code this, given the number-letter combinations.

```
 library(ggpubr)
 set.seed(12345)
 df1 = data.frame(a=c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5), rep("c",7), rep("d",10)), 
      b=rnorm(30, 6, 2), 
      c=rnorm(30, 12, 3.5), 
      d=rnorm(30, 8, 3),
      e=rnorm(30, 4, 1),
      f=rnorm(30, 16, 6)
      )
 plot1 <- ggscatter (df1, x="b", y="c")
 plot2 <- ggscatter (df1, x="b", y="d")
 plot3 <- ggscatter (df1, x="b", y="e")
 plot4 <- ggscatter (df1, x="b", y="f")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector of column names that you want to plot for and then use `lapply` :

```
library(ggpubr)
cols <- c('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
#Or use
cols <- names(df1)[-c(1:2)]

list_plots <- lapply(cols, function(x) ggscatter(df1, 'b', x))
```

Also with a `for` loop :

```
list_plots <- vector('list', length(cols))

for(i in seq_along(cols)) {
  list_plots[[i]] <- ggscatter(df1, 'b', cols[i])
}
```

`list_plots` would have list of plots where each individual plot can be accessed like `list_plots[[1]]`,`list_plots[[2]]` and so on.

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks a lot for both options, Ronak.